# Why would adding a column to a view corrupted a table-valued function?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, view, set-returning-functions

I have a TVP `myTVP` implemented as `select val.* from vw_MyView val`.  The other day, I modified `vw_MyView`, replacing:
`select Foo,Bar from DB` with
`select Foo, Bash, Bar from DB`.

This had a strange side effect: Calling `select Bar from myTVP()` returned a column named `Bar` populated with the contents of `Bash` (despite the fact that `Bar` and `Bash` don't even have the same type).

Anonymized plan demonstrating the problem: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryJLJmqdl

Note that `Object2` and `Object1` are identical, but the output list of the left-most Nested Loop is completely different between the two plans.

Notes:

- There are no plan hints in use.  No trace flags are set.
- CheckDB found no errors.
- Using option(recompile) did not fix the issue.
- Running right-click alter on the TVP with no changes fixed the issue.
- Running right-click alter on the TVP with a name change fixed the issue, but the new TVP was identical to the previous other than the name.
- Using SQL 2014 Standard Edition.

## Questions:

1. Is it normal for adding a new column to a view to change which column
   of the view is used in by other references to that view?
2. Under what circumstances will adding a column to a view cause such behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is expected. Functions and views that use `SELECT *` end up storing part of the metadata themselves relating to the underlying columns, so it is very easy for them to get confused. I talk about this problem in the following post from 2009:

- [Bad habits to kick : using SELECT * / omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)

And also in my recent GroupBy presentation:

- [T-SQL : Bad Habits and Best Practices](https://groupby.org/go/session9)

How do you avoid this problem?

1. Don't use `SELECT *` in objects.
2. Make your functions and views `WITH SCHEMABINDING`, which means you can't modify the underlying objects without also modifying the objects that reference them (this also has the side effect of prevent `*` so win-win).
3. In this specific case, you can fix the object so that `Bar` returns the correct data by using:

   ```
   EXEC sys.sp_refreshsqlmodule @name = N'dbo.myTVP';
   ```

Incidentally, the [documentation for `sys.sp_refreshsqlmodule`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326754.aspx) describes this exact scenario:

> Updates the metadata for the specified non-schema-bound stored procedure, user-defined function, view, DML trigger, database-level DDL trigger, or server-level DDL trigger in the current database. Persistent metadata for these objects, such as data types of parameters, can become outdated because of changes to their underlying objects.

As an aside, you should never use `FROM myTVP()` but instead always specify the schema, e.g. `FROM dbo.myTVP()`. I talk about that [in an old post](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix), too.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by using Select * in the TVF. It also happens to views that use select * when columns are inserted to the underlying table between existing columns, or when columns are deleted.

This to me is the number one reason (among a few more big ones) not to use Select * *anywhere* except perhaps in an outer query that wraps a fully explicit subquery for example.